# Replace color of a image, using Lockbits

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, image-processing, bitmap

Before nothing, I'll note that I'll accept C# or VB.NET solution.

I have this old code which I'm trying to refactor to avoid the bad habits and performance inefficiency of using `GetPixel`/`SetPixel` methods:

```vbnet
<Extension>
Public Function ChangeColor(ByVal sender As Image, 
                            ByVal oldColor As Color, 
                            ByVal newColor As Color) As Image

    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(sender.Width, sender.Height, sender.PixelFormat)

    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim y As Integer = 0

    While (x < bmp.Width)

        y = 0
        While y < bmp.Height
            If DirectCast(sender, Bitmap).GetPixel(x, y) = oldColor Then
                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, newColor)
            End If
            Math.Max(Threading.Interlocked.Increment(y), y - 1)
        End While
        Math.Max(Threading.Interlocked.Increment(x), x - 1)

    End While

    Return bmp

End Function
```

So, after reading the most voted solution **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346212/can-you-change-one-colour-to-another-in-an-bitmap-image)** using `LockBits` approach, I'm trying to adapt the code to my needs, to use a `Color` as parameter instead of a sequence of bytes (because in essence they are the same):

```vbnet
<Extension>
Public Function ChangeColor(ByVal sender As Image, 
                            ByVal oldColor As Color, 
                            ByVal newColor As Color) As Image

   Dim bmp As Bitmap = DirectCast(sender.Clone, Bitmap)

   ' Lock the bitmap's bits.
   Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height)
   Dim bmpData As BitmapData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat)

    ' Get the address of the first line.
    Dim ptr As IntPtr = bmpData.Scan0

    ' Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap. 
    Dim numBytes As Integer = (bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height)
    Dim rgbValues As Byte() = New Byte(numBytes - 1) {}

    ' Copy the RGB values into the array.
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, numBytes)

    ' Manipulate the bitmap.
    For i As Integer = 0 To rgbValues.Length - 1 Step 3

      If (Color.FromArgb(rgbValues(i), rgbValues(i + 1), rgbValues(i + 2)) = oldColor) Then
          rgbValues(i) = newColor.R
          rgbValues(i + 1) = newColor.G
          rgbValues(i + 2) = newColor.B
      End If

    Next i

    ' Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap.
    Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, numBytes)

    ' Unlock the bits.
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData)

    Return bmp

End Function
```

I have two problems with the extension method: the first is that if pixelformat is not `Format24bppRgb` as the original example then all goes wrong: an "IndexOutOfRange" exception is thrown in the loop. I suppose this is because I'm reading 3 bytes (RGB) instead of 4 (ARGB), but I'm not sure how to adapt it for any source pixelformat that I can pass to the function.

The second is that if I use `Format24bppRgb` as per the original C# example, the color changes to black.

Note that I'm not sure if the original solution given in the C# question that I linked to is wrong, because as per their comments it seems it is wrong in some way.

This is the way I'm trying to use it:

```vbnet
    ' This function creates a bitmap of a solid color.
    Dim srcImg As Bitmap = ImageUtil.CreateSolidcolorBitmap(New Size(256, 256), Color.Red)
    Dim modImg As Image = srcImg.ChangeColor(Color.Red, Color.Blue)

    PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = srcImg 
    PictureBox2.BackgroundImage = modImg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I suppose this is because I'm reading 3 bytes (RGB) instead of 4 (ARGB)

Yes, that's the point. If you want to manipulate the raw image content, you must rely on the `PixelFormat`. And you must differentiate the indexed formats (8bpp or less) where pixels in the `BitmapData` are not colors but indices of a color palette.

```
public void ChangeColor(Bitmap bitmap, Color from, Color to)
{
    if (Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bitmap.PixelFormat) > 8)
    {
        ChangeColorHiColoredBitmap(bitmap, from, to);
        return;
    }

    int indexFrom = Array.IndexOf(bitmap.Palette.Entries, from);
    if (indexFrom < 0)
        return; // nothing to change

    // we could replace the color in the palette but we want to see an example for manipulating the pixels
    int indexTo = Array.IndexOf(bitmap.Palette.Entries, to);
    if (indexTo < 0)
        return; // destination color not found - you can search for the nearest color if you want

    ChangeColorIndexedBitmap(bitmap, indexFrom, indexTo);
}

private unsafe void ChangeColorHiColoredBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Color from, Color to)
{
    int rawFrom = from.ToArgb();
    int rawTo = to.ToArgb();

    BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bitmap.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    byte* line = (byte*)data.Scan0;
    for (int y = 0; y < data.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < data.Width; x++)
        {
            switch (data.PixelFormat)
            {
                case PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb:
                    byte* pos = line + x * 3;
                    int c24 = Color.FromArgb(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]).ToArgb();
                    if (c24 == rawFrom)
                    {
                        pos[0] = (byte)(rawTo & 0xFF);
                        pos[1] = (byte)((rawTo >> 8) & 0xFF);
                        pos[2] = (byte)((rawTo >> 16) & 0xFF);
                    }
                    break;
                case PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb:
                case PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb:
                    int c32 = *((int*)line + x);
                    if (c32 == rawFrom)
                        *((int*)line + x) = rawTo;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException(); // of course, you can do the same for other pixelformats, too
            }
        }

        line += data.Stride;
    }

    bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
}

private unsafe void ChangeColorIndexedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int from, int to)
{
    int bpp = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bitmap.PixelFormat);
    if (from < 0 || to < 0 || from >= (1 << bpp) || to >= (1 << bpp))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    if (from == to)
        return;

    BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(
        new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bitmap.Size),
        ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
        bitmap.PixelFormat);

    byte* line = (byte*)data.Scan0;

    // scanning through the lines
    for (int y = 0; y < data.Height; y++)
    {
        // scanning through the pixels within the line
        for (int x = 0; x < data.Width; x++)
        {
            switch (bpp)
            {
                case 8:
                    if (line[x] == from)
                        line[x] = (byte)to;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    // First pixel is the high nibble. From and To indices are 0..16
                    byte nibbles = line[x / 2];
                    if ((x & 1) == 0 ? nibbles >> 4 == from : (nibbles & 0x0F) == from)
                    {
                        if ((x & 1) == 0)
                        {
                            nibbles &= 0x0F;
                            nibbles |= (byte)(to << 4);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            nibbles &= 0xF0;
                            nibbles |= (byte)to;
                        }

                        line[x / 2] = nibbles;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // First pixel is MSB. From and To are 0 or 1.
                    int pos = x / 8;
                    byte mask = (byte)(128 >> (x & 7));
                    if (to == 0)
                        line[pos] &= (byte)~mask;
                    else
                        line[pos] |= mask;
                    break;
            }
        }

        line += data.Stride;
    }

    bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

Comment: So I have added examples for the 1, 4, 8, 24, and 32 bpp pixel formats. Of course, you can calculate the colors for 15/16/64 and other formats, too. I used unsafe methods here, but you can use `Marshal.Copy` to copy the data there and back by using a managed array.

Answer (score 2):

There are three different problems in the code you posted:

1. You have the color component order wrong. The `Bitmap` class stores pixel values as integers, in little-endian format. This means that the byte order of the components is actually BGR (or BGRA for 32bpp).
2. In VB.NET, you can't directly compare `Color` values. I don't know enough about VB.NET to know why that is, but I assume it's a normal language behavior related to how VB.NET treats value types. To correctly compare `Color` values, you need to call `ToArgb()`, which returns an `Integer` value, which can be compared directly.
3. Your `For` loop uses the wrong ending value. If you only subtract `1` from the length of the array, then it is possible for the loop to run into the padding at the end of a row, but find too few bytes to successfully add `2` to the loop index and still remain within the array.

Here's a version of your extension method that works fine for me:

```vb
<Extension>
Public Function ChangeColor(ByVal image As Image, ByVal oldColor As Color, ByVal newColor As Color)
    Dim newImage As Bitmap = New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, image.PixelFormat)

    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
        g.DrawImage(image, Point.Empty)
    End Using

    ' Lock the bitmap's bits.
    Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height)
    Dim bmpData As BitmapData = newImage.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, newImage.PixelFormat)

    ' Get the address of the first line.
    Dim ptr As IntPtr = bmpData.Scan0

    ' Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap. 
    Dim numBytes As Integer = (bmpData.Stride * newImage.Height)
    Dim rgbValues As Byte() = New Byte(numBytes - 1) {}

    ' Copy the RGB values into the array.
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, numBytes)

    ' Manipulate the bitmap.
    For i As Integer = 0 To rgbValues.Length - 3 Step 3

        Dim testColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(rgbValues(i + 2), rgbValues(i + 1), rgbValues(i))

        If (testColor.ToArgb() = oldColor.ToArgb()) Then
            rgbValues(i) = newColor.B
            rgbValues(i + 1) = newColor.G
            rgbValues(i + 2) = newColor.R
        End If

    Next i

    ' Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap.
    Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, numBytes)

    ' Unlock the bits.
    newImage.UnlockBits(bmpData)

    Return newImage

End Function
```

As far as this goes:

> I'm not sure how to adapt it for any source pixelformat that I can pass to the function.

Unfortunately, the API does not directly return the bits-per-pixel or bytes-per-pixel for the bitmap. You can generalize your code to take into account the number of bytes per pixel, but you'll still have to at least map the `PixelFormat` value to that bytes per pixel value.

Comment: Thankyou for answer! In that case I will evaluate some pixelformats then throw a NotImplemented exception for unknown pixelformat. Could you please mention, or provide an url (from wikipedia? MSDN or other source) where to know each bytes-per-pixel of common pixelformats? by the moment I have: `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb = 3, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb = 4,PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb = 4`

Comment: Seems that in WPF we can get the bits-per-pixel: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformat.bitsperpixel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx