# C# Removing a certain line in Graphics/Drawing

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

Is it possible to remove some lines in my graphic panel without erasing the rest?

`PanelGraphics.Clear(Color.Black);` erases all the graphics but I only want to remove one line, or a certain color.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to remove some lines in my graphic panel without erasing the rest?

Not really. The `Graphics` does not tell you anything about the actual context, it can be the screen, a printer, a bitmap, a metafile, the surface of a control or something similar. If you draw a `Panel` or a control you must always re-draw the whole content once it is invalidated. Otherwise, you will get a messy result. Just try to move your window partly out of the screen, the custom-drawn content will be "erased" unless you redraw it.

However, if you have a concrete image, such as a `Bitmap`, you can replace its colors; however, you must know the exact `PixelFormat` of the image. See my answer here if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33562891/5114784

Comment: Thanks for the information. :) And thanks for the interesting link.